# TensorFlow AttributeError: module tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.lite has no attribute TFLiteConverter

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert a frozen graph file (.pb) to a TensorFlow Lite FlatBuffer file (.tflite) in Raspberry Pi 3B+ Linux.  TensorFlow was installed in Python using pip3; TensorFlow Lite was installed and built (static library) from source. TensorFlow version (installed in Python) is 1.11.0.

I am getting this error:
Attributeerror: module 'tensorflow.contrib.lite.python.lite' has no attribute 'TFLiteConverter'.

Here is the Python code (derived from https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api):

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tensorflow as tf
print("tf version = " + tf.version)
graph_def_file = "/home/pi/sols/demo/src/image_classification/network/fruit_models/frozen_graph.pb"
input_arrays = ["X"]
output_arrays = ["softmax"]
converter = tf.contrib.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_frozen_graph(
graph_def_file, input_arrays, output_arrays)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The TfliteConverter and TocoConverter seem to be very problematic on all OS except Mac. You can still convert the model to TensorFlow Lite using the following steps:

1. Create a new Google Colab notebook
2. Write the code to convert the model. Import TFLiteConverter and other stuff.
3. Upload the model in the notebook.
4. Run the notebook.
5. Download the generated TFLite file.

You can use [this notebook](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUIn9ffk5ICKujqPyuGaHL2irQ9Wmtpm/view?usp=drivesdk).

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.  The call converter.convert() gives this error:

RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
...

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't help.  The call converter.convert() gives this error:

RuntimeError: TOCO failed see console for info.
...
tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/graph_transformations/resolve_constant_random_uniform.cc:85] RandomUniform op outputting "dropout/random_uniform/RandomUniform" is truly random (using /dev/random system entropy). Therefore, cannot resolve as constant. Set "seed" or "seed2" attr non-zero to fix this\n2018-12-12 22:36:17.915000:

Any idea how this can be fixed?

Comment: Did you try it in the Google Colab

Comment: Yes, I did.  The above error message is from Google Colab.

Comment: Did you use LSTM or BatchNormalization or some other layer rather Dense or Conv layers

Comment: No.  We only used conv, maxpool and fully-connected (dense).

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the docs reflect the latest release. In 1.11.0, it probably had a different name and was renamed to TFLiteConverter.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it depends on tensorflow version that you are using:

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> dir(tf.contrib.lite)
['DecodeError', 'Interpreter', 'OpHint', 'PY3', 'TocoConverter', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', '_freeze_graph', '_freeze_saved_model', '_get_tensors_from_tensor_names', '_global_variables_initializer', '_graph_pb2', '_import_graph_def', '_is_frozen_graph', '_keras', '_session', '_set_tensor_shapes', '_signature_constants', '_tag_constants', '_tensor_name', '_text_format', '_tf_graph_util', 'absolute_import', 'build_toco_convert_protos', 'constants', 'convert_op_hints_to_stubs', 'division', 'print_function', 'toco_convert', 'toco_convert_protos']
>>> tf.__version__
'1.10.0'
```

So in older versions it's `TocoConverter`

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/lite/TocoConverter